# Overloading assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

We can overload assignment operator as a normal function, but we cannot overload assignment operator as a friend function. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Because the C++ Standard says so, Article 13.5.3/1:

> An assignment operator shall be
>   implemented by a non-static member
>   function with exactly one parameter.
>   Because a copy assignment operator
>   operator= is implicitly declared for a
>   class if not declared by the user
>   (12.8), a base class assignment
>   operator is always hidden by the copy
>   assignment operator of the derived
>   class.

That's all you really need to know. A friend function is not a member function, so it cannot be used to overload the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to write:

MyClassObject = MyFriendObject;

Then you would want to implement a constructor that takes a const reference to the friend class as it's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between **overloading by friend function** and **overloading by member function** is that the calling object must be the first operand in **overloading by member function**, while there is no restriction in **overloading by friend function**. This is the reason behind the standard. Similarly, some other operators requiring the first operand to be the calling function must be overloaded using member functions (examples:  `=, [], ->,` and `( )`).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "extend" the assignment operator with a "free function" outside the class, but you *can* design the class so it will allow it:

Data.h

```
class Data {
public:
    Data& operator=(const Data& lhs) { /*...*/; return *this; }
    template <typename T> Data& operator=(const T& lhs) {
        return assign(*this, lhs); // Magic right here...
    }
private:
    // ...
};
```

Point.h

```
class Point {
public:
    float x,y;
    Point& operator=(const Point& lhs) { x = lhs.x, y = lhs.y; return *this; }
    template <typename T> Point& operator=(const T& lhs) {
        return assign(*this, lhs); // Magic right here...
    }
};
```

Assignment.h

```
Data& assign(const Data& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    lhs["x"] = rhs.x;
    lhs["y"] = rhs.y;
    return lhs;
}

Point& assign(const Point& lhs, const Data& rhs) {
    rhs.query("x", lhs.x) || rhs.query(0, lhs.x);
    rhs.query("y", lhs.y) || rhs.query(1, lhs.y);
    return lhs;
}
```